# Docker and django No module named 'corsheaders'

Tags: python, django, docker

Im trying to dockerize an existing django project.

I have corsheaders installed

and its included in my installed apps as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

and in the middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
```

after that i build my docker using

```
docker-compose --build
```

and then run it

```
docker-compose up
```

but always the same error

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

i have tried to delete corsheaders from my installed aps but then i get

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'restframework'
```

ps: if i run the server through `py manage.py runserver` it works perfectly.

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Requirements.txt

```
Django>=4.0
psycopg2>=2.8
django-cors-headers==3.10.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
pandas
```

Comment: Can you share the file `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by realizing the when i install the package through :

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

its not getting installed in the venv of the project itself.
or through:

```
py -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

So i copied it to the venv and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add restframework and pass the cors at the end

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',

]


FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
```

Comment: Now the error is : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

Comment: you have in you requirements  django-cors-headers==3.10.1

djangorestframework==3.13.1 @Ezz in that order

Comment: still the same error @lana

Comment: what happens is that you are not installing it when building your container, you could add how you have your Dockerfile configuration

Comment: I updated my answer to something like I have the dockerfile

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work